# Flutter & iOS : failed to post request unexpected character

Tags: ios, flutter, request

I have flutter app have login request failed to complete.

the request :

```
login(email, password) async {
    var url = Uri.parse('http://xxxxxxx.com/api/login');
    try {
      var response =
          await http.post(url, body: {"email": email, "password": password});
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (data['message'] == 'succed') {
        Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
        prefs.setString('email', email);

        prefs.setString('token', data['token']);

        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
          ),
        );
      }}
```

the request is succed in androiod but when I run it in iOS it is failed ,I have add this to

```
info.plist
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

I have get this error :

> An Observatory debugger and profiler on iPhone 11 Pro Max is available
> at: http://127.0.0.1:50043/m2RulnUU9ek=/ The Flutter DevTools debugger
> and profiler on iPhone 11 Pro Max is available at:
> http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:50043/m2RulnUU9ek=/
> flutter: FormatException: Unexpecte character (at character 1)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just by put the body of request outside the request by save them in variable and put the variable inside body :

```
login(email, password) async {
    var url = Uri.parse('http://xxxxxxx.com/api/login');
    try {
      var list = {"email": email, "password": password}; //----- add this line
      var response =
          await http.post(url, body: list); //-----put list here
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (data['message'] == 'succed') {
        Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
        prefs.setString('email', email);

        prefs.setString('token', data['token']);

        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
          ),
        );
      }}
```